# Rendering is grey blank?

Tags: rendering, camera

Does anybody know why my camera is not showing anything and the Rendering is grey blank?

[image]

Rendering:
[image]

Camera View:
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure you have selected the good camera? To make a camera active, you need to select it then ctrl 0 (and not simply 0), the active camera has its triangle full orange

Comment: it is the only camera and it is active since it has the full orange triangle on top. I added the blend file.

Comment: i just increased it to 10m and 25m. No change.

Comment: sorry it's the Clip End  ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your camera *Clip End* is to low, increase it a bit:

[image]